# select an entry each month using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dictionary model like this:

```
const dictionarySchema = new Schema({
    entry: String,
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

and I want to select this entry each month after its creation date.

How you do this ?

Something like this gives me the entries older than a month, but this is not what I want:

```
const conditions = { 
    created: { $lt: minusDays(new Date(), 30) },    
}
const dicEntry = await dbs['en'].Dictionary.find(conditions);
```

I want a solution to select the entry every 30 days from its creation date.

Comment: Instead of new Date() , try Date.now();

Answer (score 0):

You might need to contraing the search to the day 30 days ago at 00:00:00 and the next day at 00:00:00

```js
const thirtyDaysAgoStart = new Date();
thirtyDaysAgoStart.setDate(thirtyDaysAgoStart.getDate() - 30);
thirtyDaysAgoStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);


// I'm not sure if milliseconds might be important here so I'll just go with 00:00:00 of the day after and use $lt
const thirtyDaysAgoEnd = new Date(thirtyDaysAgoStart);
thirtyDaysAgoEnd.setDate(thirtyDaysAgoEnd.getDate() + 1);



dictionarySchema.find({ created: { $gte: thirtyDaysAgoStart, $lt: thirtyDaysAgoEnd } }, (err, entries) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(entries);
  }
});
```

As youre doing right now

```
created: { $lt: minusDays(new Date(), 30) },
```

you get all created 30 days ago, 31 days ago, 32 days ago, 33 days ago, etc...

Comment: I want to query each entry "each 30 days" not entries of the 30 days ago..

Comment: @user21189833 Entries created 30 days ago is exactly what you want, going by your original code. If by "each 30 days" you mean to select the same entry every 30 days period then you should add an ID and save that for future queries. If that's still not what you want I'll need you to explain better or maybe show an example of what you have and what you expect to select with dates (current date, returned date, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

you can utilize the $expr operator in MongoDB along with the $mod operator to calculate the number of days that have passed since the entry's creation date.

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const conditions = { 
    $expr: {
        $eq: [
            { $mod: [{ $subtract: [currentDate, '$created'] }, 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000] },
            0
        ]
    }
};

const dicEntry = await dbs['en'].Dictionary.find(conditions);
```

hope it's useful